# name a column and then call items with name instead of index

Tags: python, names

I have a list of columns that I will be analyzing.  Instead of referring back to the specific index such as data[1][2], I'd like to assign a name to a column and then loop through the rows of the columns for different tasks.  How do I assign a name to a column and then is this the correct format to refer back to it?

```
for x in range (len(data)):  
    if [column_name][x] ....
```

Comment: Is this in Python?  Need more info...

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's python.  I'm trying to use the solutions offered but not having luck.  I get errors saying I can't index with a string.  I'm having trouble assigning the column name and then successfully referencing it.  The data is from a txt document.  My 2nd column is ID, my third column is weight and my 4th column is height.  How do I name them and refer back?

Answer (score 3):

There's a bunch of different ways of doing this.  If you know the association between names and columns at the time you write your code, the easiest way by far is this:

```
for row in data:
   (foo, bar, baz, bat) = row
```

...assuming that you don't need to update `row` (and `data`).

If you need to update the row, copying the values to variables won't work.  You need to manipulate the items via their indexes.  In that case, aviraldg's approach is simplest:

```
(foo, bar, baz, bat) = range(4)
for row in data:
   row[foo] = row[bar]
```

If you want to reference the columns by a *string* that contains their name, you'll need to copy the row to a dictionary whose key is the column name.  Then, when you're done manipulating the dictionary, you need to update the original list, or replace it with a new one (which is what this code does):

```
columns = ("foo", "bar", "baz", "bat")
for i in range(len(data)):
   d = dict(zip(columns, data[i]))
   d["foo"] = d["bar"]
   data[i] = [d[col] for col in columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to use names instead of integers to access your data is to use a dictionary

```
data = {'pig':[1, 2], 'cow':[3, 4], 'dog':[5,6]}

if data in range(2):
    if data['dog'][1]==4:...
```

There are other ways as well.  For example, you could make a class and override `__getitem__`; or you could just assign variable names to column numbers in a 2d array, like `dog=2`, etc; it all depends on exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is store a column in a variable and then reference it, instead of always using the subscript. Simple enough:

```
varName=data[columnName]
```

For consequent accesses to that column, `varName[rowName]` should do the trick